# how to resolve this firebase module versioning error?

Tags: react-native

Here's a list of my firebase dependencies in package.json:

```
"@react-native-firebase/admob": "^6.2.0",
"@react-native-firebase/app": "^6.2.0",
"@react-native-firebase/auth": "^6.2.0",
"@react-native-firebase/crashlytics": "^6.2.0",
"@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^6.2.0",
```

I just added the last "messaging" dependency in that list and then ran npm install.  I included the following import for a component:

```
import messaging from '@react-native-firebase/messaging';
```

Then I included the following line of code in one of the component functions:

```
      const enabled = await firebase.messaging().hasPermission();
```

My app is currently returning the following error:

```
Error: Requiring module "node_modules\@react-native-firebase\messaging\lib\index.js", which threw an exception: Error: You've attempted to require '@react-native-firebase\messaging' version '6.3.4', however, the '@react-native-firebase\app' module is of a different version (6.2.0).  All React Native Firebase modules must be of the same version.  Please ensure they match up in your package.json file and re-run yarn/npm install

I inspected my project's node_modules\@react-native-firebase\messaging\package.json.  Here's a subset of some of the version refs within that file:

  "_from": "@react-native-firebase/messaging@^6.2.0",
  "_id": "@react-native-firebase/messaging@6.3.4",
  "_requested": {
    "raw": "@react-native-firebase/messaging@^6.2.0",
    "rawSpec": "^6.2.0",
    "fetchSpec": "^6.2.0"
  },
  "_resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@react-native-firebase/messaging/-/messaging-6.3.4.tgz",
  "_spec": "@react-native-firebase/messaging@^6.2.0",
  "version": "6.3.4"
```

So it looks like the ^6.2.0 version spec that I configured is getting read as expected, but then some aspect of the npm install process redirects the install to version 6.3.4.  Any idea why this is happening?  All of the firebase modules are required to be of the same version, so if I want to use the firebase messaging module then do I need to set the version to all of the other firebase modules to "^6.3.0" in my project's package.json?  Or do I have other options for a workaround?